# NDSolve for system of PDEs -Error: fewer dependent variables!

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mass-transport, axisymmetry

I am trying to solve the equations below to find the breakthrough curve in an adsorption process:

```
∂C/∂t+u* ∂C/∂z+ρ/ϵ * ∂q/∂t=  0
∂q/∂t= -Ks * (q-(qm* b*C)/(1+ b*C))

the IC and BCs are: 
q(t=0,z)=0
C(t,z=0)=C0
C(t=0,z) = 0
```

The parameters are given as:

```
eps = 0.373
ueps = 6.66
C0 = 892
Ks = 0.0872
rho = 390.04
qm = 7.0136
b = 0.05313
```

I wrote the equation in Mathematica as below:

```
s=NDSolve[{∂_t C[t,z]==-ueps*∂_z C[t,z]+(rho⁄eps)*Ks*(q[t,z]-(qm*b*(C[t,z])⁄((1+b*C[t,z])))),∂_t q[t,z]==-Ks*(q[t,z]-(qm*b*(C[t,z])⁄((1+b*C[t,z])))),DirichletCondition[{C[t,0]==C0},True],C[0,z]==0,q[0,z]==0},{C,q},{t,0,60},{z,0,22}]
```

[image]

After evaluating the notebook, I receive this error:
NDSolve: There are fewer dependent variables, {q[t,z]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.

I have been trying to fix this problem by rearranging the equations, but no success yet.

I appreciate it if you could please help me solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe my [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1470321) on Chemical adsorption in fixed beds on the Wolfram Community website will give you some ideas.

Comment: Keep in mind, C is a reserved letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update:  Mass Transport Tutorial

In my answer, I adapted the Heat Transfer Tutorial to handle Mass Transport.  There is a new and fairly extensive [Mass Transport Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html) that you can use directly.  In my answer
[227821](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/227821/61809), I extended the Mass Transport functions in the tutorial to include axisymmetric and optional porosity.

## Update: Extended Answer

To use the FEM method it is good to cast your equations into coefficient form as shown [FEM Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601).

$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

The benefits of coefficient form include:

- Standardization so others can quickly interpret your equations
- Avoidance of sign errors
- Nice one-to-one mapping with other FEM codes such as COMSOL

For advective-diffusive problems with and without source terms, the [Heat transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) is a good place to start to learn how to set up these types of problems. It shows how to properly setup the PDE operators in coefficient form. The `TimeHeatTransferModel` function in the [Heat Transfer Tutorial](https://wolfram.com/xid/0hqp56s8dz09d27n66vyfgbsvtjae0yi-qf1jv0) can help guide you on how to setup the problem.

### Create Fluid and Solid PDE Operators Using Heat Transfer Tutorial

The following shows how one can setup your coupled system of interphase transport of the fluid and solid using the `TimeHeatTransferModel` :

```
(* From Vitaliy Kaurov for nice display of operators *)
pdConv[f_] := 
 TraditionalForm[
  f /. Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :> 
    Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &, 
     Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
        Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}]]
(*PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransferVerificationTests#\
463435833*)
ClearAll[HeatTransferModel]
HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
  Module[{V, Q, a = k},
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, ρ*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[ FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[ VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (* Note the - sign in the operator *)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]
TimeHeatTransferModel[T_, TimeVar_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, 
  Velocity_, Source_] := ρ*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
  HeatTransferModel[T, X, k, ρ, Cp, Velocity, Source]
(* Create Parametric PDE Operators for Fluid and Solid *)
(* Include Small Diffusive Term to Fluid Otherwise MMA Might Complain \
about Being Convection Dominated *)
parmfop = 
  TimeHeatTransferModel[c[t, x], t, {x}, {d}, 1, 
   1, {u}, -(ρ/ϵ) Q];
parmsop = 
  TimeHeatTransferModel[q[t, x], t, {x}, {0}, 1, 1, "NoFlow", Q];
parmfop // pdConv
parmsop // pdConv
```

[image: PDE Operators]

Slight rearrangement shows the operators follow coefficient form:

$$\begin{matrix}
m\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u & +\ \ d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u & + \ \ \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) u &  + \ \ \beta \cdot\nabla u & + \ \ au & -\ \ f & =0 & \ \ (1) \\
 & & & & & & \\
 & +\ \ \frac{{\partial c(t,x)}}{{\partial t}} & + \ \  {\nabla _{\left\{ x \right\}}}\cdot\left( {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - d} 
\end{array}} \right).{\nabla _{\left\{ x \right\}}}c\left( {t,x} \right)} \right) &  + \ \ \left\{ u \right\}.{\nabla _{\left\{ x \right\}}}c\left( {t,x} \right) &  & +\ \ \frac{{\rho Q}}{\varepsilon } & =0 & \ \ (2) \\
 & & & & & & \\
 & +\ \ \frac{{\partial q(t,x)}}{{\partial t}} &   &   & & -\ \ Q
 & =0 & \ \ (3)
\end{matrix}$$

### New Workflow

The following workflow uses the PDE operators defined above and produces an annotated plots that can be scrolled frame-by-frame with manipulate.

```
(* Define Parameters *)
eps = 0.373;
ueps = 6.66;
c0 = 892;
Ks = 0.0872;
rho = 390.04;
qm = 7.0136;
b = 0.05313;
tend = 60;
xend = 22;
Qsource = -Ks*(q[t, x] - (qm*b*c[t, x])/(1 + b*c[t, x]));
timeinc = 0.25; (* Output times *)
(* Critical Breakthrough Fraction *)
btfrac = 0.05; 
(* Use CombinePlots For Secondary Axis *)
cp = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots", "Function"];
(* Setup PDE System *)
pdef = (parmfop == 0) /. {ϵ -> eps, u -> ueps, ρ -> rho,
     d -> 1, Q -> Qsource};
pdes = (parmsop == 0) /. {Q -> Qsource};
dc = DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == c0 (1 - Exp[-40 t]), x == 0];
icf = c[0, x] == 0;
ics = q[0, x] == 0;
(* Solve PDE *)
{cifn, qifn} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pdef, pdes, dc, icf, ics}, {c, q}, {t, 0, tend}, {x, 
    0, xend}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}];
(* Plot Solutions *)
(* Define Plot Function Using Combine Plots *)
bfn = Function[{t}, 
   If[cifn[t, xend] >= btfrac c0, xend, 
    x /. FindRoot[cifn[t + 0.01, x] - btfrac c0, {x, 0, xend}, 
      Method -> "Brent"]]];
bttemp = With[{xbt = #}, 
    If[xbt == xend, "Sat", 
     StringTemplate["x=``"][ToString@PaddedForm[xbt, {4, 2}]]]] &;
pltfn = Function[{t}, cp[
    With[{xbt = bfn[t]}, 
     Plot[Callout[cifn[t, x], bttemp[xbt], xbt, RoundingRadius -> 5, 
       Appearance -> "SlantedLabel"], {x, 0, xend}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2, xend + 1}, {-10, 1.1 c0}}, Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {"x", "c"}, 
      PlotLabel -> 
       Style[StringTemplate[
          "Fluid and Solid Concentrations @ time=``"][
         ToString@PaddedForm[t, {4, 2}]], 12], 
      Epilog -> {Green, Thick, Dashed, 
        Line[{{xbt, -10}, {xbt, 1.1 c0}}]}]],
    Plot[qifn[t, x], {x, 0, xend}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 7},
     Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Red, 
     FrameLabel -> {"x", "q"}],
    "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"
    ], Listable];
(* Create Image List and Manipulate *)
imgs = Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> 340] & /@ 
   pltfn[Range[0, tend, timeinc]];
Manipulate[imgs[[i]], {i, 1, tend/timeinc, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Annotated Adsorption Animation]

## Original Answer

I would cast the problem using the following workflow:

```
(* Define Parameters *)
eps = 0.373;
ueps = 6.66;
c0 = 892;
Ks = 0.0872;
rho = 390.04;
qm = 7.0136;
b = 0.05313;
tend = 60;
xend = 22;
Qsource = -Ks*(q[t, x] - (qm*b*c[t, x])/(1 + b*c[t, x]));
(* Use CombinePlots For Secondary Axis *)
cp = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"];
(* Define Parametric PDE operators *)
(* Include Small Diffusive Term to Fluid Otherwise MMA Might Complain \
about Being Convection Dominated *)
parmfop = 
  D[c[t, x], t] +  D[-d D[c[t, x], x], x] + u  D[c[t, x], x] + (
   Q ρ)/ϵ;
parmsop = D[q[t, x], t] - Q;
(* Setup PDE System *)
pdef = (parmfop == 0) /. {ϵ -> eps, u -> ueps, ρ -> rho,
     d -> 1, Q -> Qsource};
pdes = (parmsop == 0) /. {Q -> Qsource};
dc = DirichletCondition[c[t, x] == c0 (1 - Exp[-40 t]), x == 0];
icf = c[0, x] == 0;
ics = q[0, x] == 0;
(* Solve PDE *)
{cifn, qifn} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pdef, pdes, dc, icf, ics}, {c, q}, {t, 0, tend}, {x, 
    0, xend}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}];
(* Plot Solutions *)
(* Define Plot Function Using Combine Plots *)
pltfn = Function[{t}, cp[
    Plot[cifn[t, x], {x, 0, xend}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1 c0}, 
     Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "c"}],
    Plot[qifn[t, x], {x, 0, xend}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 7},
     Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Red, 
     FrameLabel -> {"x", "q"}],
    "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"
    ], Listable];
(* Create Image List and Animate *)
imgs = Rasterize /@ pltfn[Range[0, tend, 0.25]];
ListAnimate[imgs, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Solution Animation]