# NDSolve PDE of function u[x,t], boundary condition needs to feed an expression of t into u[x,t] as x

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to obtain a range of numerical solutions of the following convection-diffusion-reaction equation:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+0.01\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=-10^{-12}\frac{\partial^2u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+10
^6\cdot \left(u(x,t)\right)^2+\left(10^6\cdot10^{-8}\cdot10^{-8}-10^{-3}(10^{-8}+10^{-8})\right)\cdot u(x,t)+10^6\cdot 10^{-8} \cdot 10^{-8}$$

With the initial and boundary conditions:

$$u(0,t)=0\\u(x,0)=0\\\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}|_{x=0.01t}=0$$

I used NDSolve as the following:

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] + 0.01*D[u[x, t], x] == -10^-12*D[u[x, t], x, x] + 10^6*(u[x, t])^2 + (10^6*10^-8*10^-8 - 10^-3*(10^-8 + 10^-8)) u[x, t] + 10^6*10^-8*10^-8
uval = NDSolve[{eqn, u[0, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == 0, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 0.01 t) == 0}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 600}]
```

As you can see, the boundary condition $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}|_{x=0.01t}=0$ feeds $0.01t$ as $x$ into the partial derivative of $u(x, t)$ with respect to $x$. But running this in Wolfram Mathematica gives the following error:

```
NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.
```

Apparently NDSolve doesn't accept feeding an independent variable as another independent variable into a multivariable function. How do I solve this?

Comment: Flux conditions are applied on an elemental basis.  For example, a 1-D problem would be applied to a `LineElement` that is specified with 2 points.  What is the meaning of applying a zero flux condition at a singular point?

Comment: You may want to check for sign errors as you have a negative diffusion coefficient.  Also, are your trying to represent a moving boundary with your flux condition?

Comment: @TimLaska Yes, this is a model of Lateral-Flow Immuno-Assay, which involves the movement of a liquid through a membrane with a constant velocity, and hence indicating a moving boundary. About the issues you have mentioned, I also find the negative diffusion coefficient weird, but this equation is directly adopted from a published research paper... So I don't really know if it's my problem or the authors'. (The title of that paper is "A mathematical model to predict the optimal test line location and sample volume for lateral flow immunoassays")

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find a pdf of the paper and I am also traveling for the next few days.  What I gathered online is that the LFIA is chromatography like problem consisting of a mobile and stationary phase (the stationary phase has at least a test and control region).  You can break this into a coupled problem as I did on this adsorption problem answer [226609](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226609/61809) .

Comment: @TimLaska Thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: @Maxivator Is it really problem with negative viscosity of $-10^{-12}$ or it is just a typo?

Comment: @TimLaska There is basic paper from where the model been taken   https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1126&context=meam_papers