# Stefan problem with mixed bc

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I am trying to solve through Mathematica the classical Stefan problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\dot{v}(x,t)=v_{xx}(x,t) & x\in(0,s(t))\\
\dot{s}(t)=-v_x(s(t),t) & x = s(t)\\
v(0,t) = 0 & x = 0\\
v(x,0) = v_0(x) & \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
**with the novelty that** the boundary condition on the moving front is not the usual $v(s(t),t)=0$, but rather
$$
 \displaystyle\color{red}{v_x(s(t),t) - \frac{1}{s(t)} v(s(t),t) = F(t)}
 $$
with $F(t)$ some given function. I have tried to understand how [the great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58622/91964) of @ybeltukov could be modified, even (say) in the simple case of
$$
 F(t)=t, \qquad 
 v_0(x)=x
 $$
But I have been scratching my head uselessly for days ... I hope somebody could give me a grind on this!

Thanks so much!

Comment: There're many other related posts in this site, e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211080/1871 (Don't miss the links in comment), have you read them?

Comment: Hi @xzczd, I think I've spent the whole week to read the various posts and suggested method of implementation of Stefan problem; nobody considers general types of bc on the moving front. Which is crucial for my research ...  :/

Comment: I don't think there's anything special in your b.c., it's merely a Robin b.c. involving $s(t)$ term. Please think carefully about change of variable, and play with `DChange`/`DSolveChangeVariables`.

Comment: Another related post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269866/1871

Comment: It is not clear what initial condition $v_0(x)=x$ means in this case? If $0\le x\le s(t)$ and $s(0)=0$ then $v_0(x)=0$. Should we suppose that  $s(0)>0$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, in my specific case I will assume $v_0(x)=0$, but I was just willing to think of the possibility that this is not the case, as far as I am aware in PDEs the initial condition ought not to be $v_0(x)=0$; also note this looks like Stefan problem but it isn't so.

Comment: and thanks so much for sharing the specific location of pertinent comments, I had not understood that these contain elements to adapt @ybeltukov ' solution to embed Robin's conditions. I will give it a try and get back .... but thanks for now!

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved with using the Euler wavelets collocation method as follows. We introduce same normalized variable as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/pde-with-stefan-conditions-a-k-a-variable-boundary/58622#58622) in the form $x\rightarrow \frac {x}{s(t)}$. First, we test code utilizing numerical solution from @ybeltukov [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/pde-with-stefan-conditions-a-k-a-variable-boundary/58622#58622)

```
OEm[m_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2 m + 
    1] Sum[(-1)^(m - k) x^k Binomial[m, k] Binomial[m + k, k], {k, 0, 
    m}]; UE[m_, t_] := OEm[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^((k - 1)/2) UE[m, 2^(k - 1) t - n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]; 
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4;
With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
  nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}];
Psijk = With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
wA = Table[wa[i][t], {i, nn}]; wB = Table[wb[i][t], {i, 2}];
v2[x_] := wA . Psi[x]; v1[x_] := wA . int1[x] + wB[[1]];
v0[x_] := wA . int2[x] + wB[[1]] x + wB[[2]];
equ = {D[v0[x], t] + (x v1[1] v1[x])/s[t]^2 == v2[x]/
   s[t]^2}; eqnS = {s'[t] == -v1[1]/s[t]};
eqx = Table[equ, {x, xcol}];
eqs = Join[Flatten[eqx], eqnS];

bc = Join[{v1[0] + s[t] == 0}, {v0[1] == 0}]; icx = {v0[x] == 0 /. 
   t -> 0}; ic = Table[icx, {x, xcol}] // Flatten;
varAll = Join[wA, wB, {s[t]}];
icn = Join[ic, bc /. t -> 0, {s[0] == 10^-3}]; eqnN = 
 Join[eqs, D[bc, t]]; var1 = D[varAll, t];
{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqnN, var1];

f = Inverse[mat // N] . (-vec);

vr0 = varAll /. t -> 0; {w0, mat0} = CoefficientArrays[icn, vr0];

s0 = Inverse[mat0 // N] . (-w0); rul0 = 
 Table[vr0[[i]] -> s0[[i]], {i, Length[vr0]}];
f0 = f /. t -> 0 /. rul0; m = Length[f];

sol = NDSolve[{Table[var1[[i]] == f[[i]], {i, Length[var1]}], 
    Table[vr0[[i]] == s0[[i]], {i, Length[vr0]}]}, varAll, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization and comparison with @ybeltukov solution (dashed lines)

```
lst = Table[{{t, x}, v0[x] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1, .1}, {x, 0, 
   1, .1}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lst, 1]]; S = 
 Interpolation[Table[{t, s[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1, .01}]];
{Show[{DensityPlot[
   u[t, x/S[t]] UnitStep[S[t] - x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  Plot[s[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]}],Plot[{u[t, 0], u[1, t/S[1]] UnitStep[S[1] - t], S[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note, that two numerical solution are in a good agreement, therefore we can try to solve problem proposed by Josè. In this case we consider solution with initial data $v(x,0)=vini(x)=x, s(0)=3$, we have

```
s0 = 3; F[t_] := t; vini[x_] := x; tmax = 1.;

OEm[m_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2 m + 
    1] Sum[(-1)^(m - k) x^k Binomial[m, k] Binomial[m + k, k], {k, 0, 
    m}]; UE[m_, t_] := OEm[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^((k - 1)/2) UE[m, 2^(k - 1) t - n + 1], (n - 1)/
       2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4;
With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
  nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}];
Psijk = With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
wA = Table[wa[i][t], {i, nn}]; wB = Table[wb[i][t], {i, 2}];
v2[x_] := wA . Psi[x]; v1[x_] := wA . int1[x] + wB[[1]];
v0[x_] := wA . int2[x] + wB[[1]] x + wB[[2]];
equ = {D[v0[x], t] + (x v1[1] v1[x])/s[t]^2 == 
   v2[x]/s[t]^2}; eqnS = {s'[t] == -v1[1]/s[t]};
eqx = Table[equ, {x, xcol}];
eqs = Join[Flatten[eqx], eqnS];

bc = Join[{v0[0] == 0}, {v1[1] - v0[1] == s[t] F[t]}]; icx = {v0[x] ==
     vini[x] s0 /. t -> 0}; ic = Table[icx, {x, xcol}] // Flatten;
varAll = Join[wA, wB, {s[t]}];
icn = Join[ic, bc /. t -> 0, {s[0] == s0}]; eqnN = 
 Join[eqs, D[bc, t]]; var1 = D[varAll, t];

f = var1 /. Solve[eqnN, var1][[1]];

vr0 = varAll /. t -> 0; s00 = vr0 /. Solve[icn, vr0][[1]];

sol = NDSolve[{Table[var1[[i]] == f[[i]], {i, Length[var1]}], 
    Table[vr0[[i]] == s00[[i]], {i, Length[vr0]}]}, 
   varAll, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

Visualization

```
S = Interpolation[
  Table[{t, s[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, tmax, .01}]]; lst = 
 Table[{{t, x}, v0[x] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, tmax, .05}, {x, 0, 
   1, .05}];
Show[{DensityPlot[
   u[t, x/S[t]] UnitStep[S[t] - x], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, S[tmax]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
  Plot[S[t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
   PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 1. Second method to solve this problem is FDM, same as @ybeltukov, but much clear

```
ns = 101; h = 1/(ns - 1);
x[t_] = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, ns}];
xgrid = Table[k h, {k, 0, ns - 1}]; M2 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; M1 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
eqnS = {s'[t] == -(M1 . x[t])[[ns]]/s[t]}; eq = 
 Table[(D[x[t], t])[[i]] + 
    xgrid[[i]] (M1 . x[t])[[ns]] (M1 . x[t])[[i]]/
      s[t]^2 == (M2 . x[t])[[i]]/s[t]^2, {i, 2, ns - 1}];
bc = {(M1 . x[t])[[1]] == -s[t], x[t][[ns]] == 0};
ini = Join[{s[0] == .001}, Table[x[0][[i]] == 0, {i, 2, ns - 1}]];

sol = NDSolve[{Join[eqnS, eq, D[bc, t]], Join[ini, bc /. t -> 0]}, 
   Join[{s[t]}, x[t]], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization and comparison with previous solution (dashed lines)

```
u = Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{{t, xgrid[[i]]}, x[t][[i]] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 
     1, .1}, {i, ns}], 1]];

S = Interpolation[Table[{t, s[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1, .001}]];

{Show[{DensityPlot[
   u[t, x/S[t]] UnitStep[S[t] - x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  Plot[S[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]}],Plot[{u[t, 0], u[1, t/S[1]] UnitStep[S[1] - t], S[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 


Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Finally we can solve problem proposed by Josè with initial data $v(x,0)=v_0(x)=x,s(0)=3$, and for $F(t)=t$, we have

```
F[t_] := t; v0[x_] := x;

ns = 101; h = 1/(ns - 1);
x[t_] = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, ns}];
xgrid = Table[k h, {k, 0, ns - 1}]; M2 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; M1 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
eqnS = {s'[t] == -(M1 . x[t])[[ns]]/s[t]}; eq = 
 Table[(D[x[t], t])[[i]] + 
    xgrid[[i]] (M1 . x[t])[[ns]] (M1 . x[t])[[i]]/
      s[t]^2 == (M2 . x[t])[[i]]/s[t]^2, {i, 2, ns - 1}];
bc = {(M1 . x[t])[[ns]] - x[t][[ns]] == s[t] F[t], x[t][[1]] == 0};
ini = Join[{s[0] == 3}, 
   Table[x[0][[i]] == 3 v0[xgrid[[i]]], {i, 2, ns - 1}]];

sol = NDSolve[{Join[eqnS, eq, D[bc, t]], Join[ini, bc /. t -> 0]}, 
   Join[{s[t]}, x[t]], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization and comparison with wavelets solution (dashed lines)

```
Show[{DensityPlot[
   u[t, x/S[t]] UnitStep[S[t] - x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 3}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  Plot[S[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]}];

Plot[{u[1, t/S[1]] UnitStep[S[t] - t], S[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Dashed, PlotLegends -> Automatic];

    u = Interpolation[
      Flatten[Table[{{t, xgrid[[i]]}, x[t][[i]] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 
         1, .1}, {i, ns}], 1]];
    
    S = Interpolation[Table[{t, s[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1, .001}]];
{Show[{DensityPlot[
   u[t, x/S[t]] UnitStep[S[t] - x], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, s0}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
  Plot[S[t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
   PlotRange -> All]}],Plot[{u[1, t/S[1]] UnitStep[S[t] - t], S[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: But this is just amazing! you can not even imagine how grateful am I ….  I would have NEVER arrived here! I will play with it and will give feedback on how it goes :) thanks heathfully!

Comment: @Josè You are welcome!

Comment: Ok so. The 1st part where you redo the solution of the Stefan problem is ok. 2nd part where you solve my problem doesn't run on my machine (Mathematica 12). Specifically the (first) problematic line is:
   `f = Inverse[mat // N].(-vec);`
Delivering several: 
    `General::munfl: 1.493*10^-237 (-7.40643*10^-238) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.`
altogether with: 
   `Inverse::sing: Matrix {<<1>>} is singular.`
Any clue? Thanks so much ...

Comment: Ah, I see that last part has no definition for `S, u` (done). Also, please run second part on the fresh kernel.

Comment: thanks so much for your patience. The problem is before that line, my first errors are immediately after `f = Inverse[mat // N].(-vec);`delivering the error messages of previous message (notably `Inverse::sing: Matrix {<<1>>} is singular.`) ... any clue? :/

Comment: @Josè  Fortunately I have v12 on my old computer. I have tested code and found out error due to matrix inversion. Solution computed with new code using `Solve` shown above.

Comment: Hi Alex Tournev, I have pretty much followed everything of your last implementation (fantastic!), apparently in your code for my problem the definition of u was still missing, I've added it as `u = Interpolation[Flatten[lst, 1]];`. Now the code runs but the graphics isn't like yours as the plot of the u(t,x) function stops half way, also I get some errors after my added line for u, `Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[lst,1].` and `Interpolation::innd: First argument in Flatten[lst,1] does not contain a list of data and coordinates.`, any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: PS it may actually have to do with my v12 Mathematica version, as I've plotted with x in (0,3) instead of x in (x,s(tmax)) and it now plots great! :) Thanks so much Alex! PS: if you like please add the `u = Interpolation[Flatten[lst, 1]];` code line as it's missing in the final solution of my problem, so maybe others in future will have no problem! :) thanks so much again!

Comment: @Josè Please, see also FDM solution as a control test.

Comment: thanks for this MASSIVE help, I've checked also the FDM method, both work now, my personal favorite at this point is the previous pone you had posted, which was very clean and I know where/how to play to modify the equation! Have a lovely Sunday and thanks immensely!!!

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I noticed my "moving grid method" is wrong 囧. Just spent 2 hours to revise all the related posts. (Of course +1. )

Answer (score 2):

Let me add my FDM solution. The spirit of this solution is the same as that of Alex's FDM solution, except that the process is automated with [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) and [`DChange`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871). Since there's nothing new in the following code compared to the previous moving boundary problems in this site, I won't explain much. (Anyway, if you still feel it difficult to follow, feel free to ask in the comment, but please be specific. )

I've chosen the same initial data as in Alex's answer so we can easily verify the result.

```
s0 = 3;
F = t; v0 = x;
With[{v = v[x, t], 
   s = s[t]}, {eq, ic, 
    bc} = {{D[v, t] == D[v, x, x], 
     D[s, t] == -D[v, x] /. x -> s}, {v == v0, s == s0} /. t -> 0, {v == 0 /. x -> 0,
      D[v, x] - 1/s v == F /. x -> s}}];
(* Definition of DChange isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)       
{neweq, newicmid, newbc} = DChange[{eq, ic, bc}, x/s[t] == ξ, x, ξ, v[x, t]]    
newic = {newicmid[[1]] /. t -> 0 /. s[0] -> s0, newicmid[[2]]};

With[{ic = newic, eq = neweq, bc = newbc},
 domain = {0, 1}; points = 25; grid = Array[# &, points, domain]; difforder = 2;
  (* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
     please find it in the link above. *)
  ptoofunc = pdetoode[v[ξ, t], t, grid, difforder];
  del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
  
  ode = {del@ptoofunc@eq[[1]], ptoofunc@eq[[2]]};
  odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
  odeic = {ic[[1]] // ptoofunc // del, ic[[2]]} /. t -> 0;
  tend = 1;
  {ssol, vsollst} = 
   NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, {s, v /@ grid}, {t, 0, tend}]; // AbsoluteTiming]

vscaledsol = rebuild[vsollst, grid, 2];
vsol = {x, t} |-> vscaledsol[x/ssol[t], t];
    
reg = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[x <= ssol[t], {{t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 3}}];

DensityPlot[vsol[x, t], {t, x} ∈ reg]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[vsol[x, t], {x, 0, ssol[t]}, PlotRange -> {{0, s0}, {-1, 5}}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is nice application of your perfect code `pdetoode` (+1).